# How to create a factory method in rust to return generic container - getting an error "doesn't have a size known at compile-time" returning generic

Tags: rust

I have a container type like this:

```
struct Container<T: Sized + MyTrait + Serialize> {
    data: T,
    key: String
}
```

wrapping this trait:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Something;
}
```

I have many concrete implementors of `MyTrait`:

```
struct S1 {}
impl MyTrait for S1 { ... };
... many kinds ...
struct S10{}
impl MyTrait for S10 { ... }
```

I have a higher level which should vend the appropriate implementation based on some decision logic (a factory of `MyTrait` types):

```
fn get_appropriate_impl(type_of_instance: SomeEnum ... ) -> Container<MyTrait> {
    ...choose appropriate implementation to return...
    return match type_of_instance {
        // each branch should return a different type
    }
}
```

I get an error

```
Container<MyTrait> {
          doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

I've tried many variations:

```
Container<Box<MyTrait>>

Box<Container<MyTrait>>

Box<Container<Box<MyTrait>>
```

each has their own errors

How do I resolve this?

PS - I've also implemented `Deref` and `DerefMut` on Container:

```
impl<T: MyTrait > Deref for Container<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

Comment: `Container<Box<MyTrait>>` can be made to work, what error do you get? Since Rust 2018 you have to write `Container<Box<dyn MyTrait>>`

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE, as well as a reproducible example.

Comment: Something like `Container<impl MyTrait>` might work, but not if you return different implementations in different branches, which is your requirement. You'll certainly need to return `Container<Box<dyn MyTrait>>`.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7a9ac7faabf9d91d1aff05bb6ac8dd96

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a trait, not an object. The size of an implementation of a trait is not known at compile time (imagine, you implement `MyTrait` for `u8` and `u16`, what size the return type would have?). The `Sized` bound does not help here (and it's implicit, too), because it only requires that `T` is `Sized`, but not `MyTrait`. Also, adding a bound to `MyTrait: Sized` does not help because it only requires, that the object, you implement `MyTrait` for, is sized, but it does not specify which size it may have.

This can be solved by either returning a concrete type, which is implementing `MyTrait` or wrapping the trait (e.g. in a `Box`). You are probably looking for the latter approach.

Returning a concrete type can be either done by adding a generic argument to the function:

```rust
fn get_appropriate_impl<T: MyTrait>() -> Container<T> {
    ...
}
```

or by using the `impl Trait` notation:

```rust
fn get_appropriate_impl() -> Container<impl MyTrait> {
    ...
}
```

However, if you don't know the return type beforehand, you probably want to store the object on the heap and return a pointer to that, e.g. by using `Box`, `Rc`, or `Arc`:

```rust
fn get_appropriate_impl() -> Container<Box<dyn MyTrait>> {
    ...
}
```

This requires you to implement `MyTrait` on `Box<dyn MyTrait>` as well, this can be done by implementing it on `Box` yourself:

```rust
impl MyTrait for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Something {
        (**self).do_something()
    }
}
```

If you know that you will only use `Box` for `Container<T>` you might want to encapsulate it there directly:

```rust
struct Container {
  data: Box<dyn MyTrait>,
}
```